# how to declare array index as boolean in function parameter in php

Tags: php, class

First look at my php script:

```
<?php
class user{
public function check_array($option['myname']=FALSE){
if($option['myname']==False){
 echo $option['yourname'];
}else{
 echo $option['myname'];
}
}
$user = new user();
$option['yourname']='Mr. X';
$option['myname']='Mamun';
$user->check_array();
?>
```

Objective is my script is to pass argument/parameter in class method call. If the parameter is an array and if I want to declare an array element as False (by default), the how to declare it in proper way.

The above code is not working. It is showing following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' ..........

How can I declare the above array element in right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function check_array(array $option) {
    $option += array('myname' => false, 'yourname' => null);

    if ($option['myname'] !== false) {
        echo $option['myname'];
    } else {
        echo $option['yourname'];
    }
}

$option = array(
    'yourname' => 'Mr. X',
    'myname'   => 'Mamun'
);
check_array($option);
```

You cannot declare the array structure and its default content as part of the function signature, it's simply not possible and arguably makes little sense. You can simply amend the array with default values programmatically inside the function with `+` though. You can also require the argument to be an `array` through type hinting, which I've done above.

I've also taken the liberty to remove anything related to `class`, since it's unnecessary for this example.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't declare** default values to keys of function arguments.
You can achieve your goal in several ways, e.g.:

```
public function check_array($option) {
    if (is_array($option) && !isset($option['myname'])) {
        $option['myname'] = false;
    }

    // do something else
}
```